# ubuntu14.04: opengl for qt development

Tags: graphics, application-development, compiling, qt, opengl

since a half day i try to get qt-creator to compile ... but i get errors.

This is the output i get, when i start to compile a standard graphical project of the qt-creator (just created this empty project and tried to compile):

```
15:49:05: Running steps for project colour-picker...
15:49:05: Skipping disabled step qmake.
15:49:05: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/bin/qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/bin/qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib -o colour-picker main.o mainwindow.o   -L/usr/local/bin/qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Gui -L/usr/lib64 -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [colour-picker] Error 1
15:49:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project colour-picker (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
15:49:05: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Sp i think the gl library is missing.
(By compiling a console-project it works. So i can see the generated empty window.)
If i search for the gl library:

```
find -name *gl.so*
./home/fabian/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfltk_gl.so.1.1
./home/fabian/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfltk_gl.so.1.1
./home/fabian/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/GarrysMod/bin/libtogl.so
./home/fabian/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Team Fortress 2/bin/libtogl.so
./usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.15.3.1
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1.0.0
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.15
./usr/lib/compiz/libopengl.so
```

.. it is found, but i think under a wrong directory and name (last entry (libopengl.so)? am I right? If so what to do?

also if i type in the console something is found:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-352/libGL.so
    libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-352/libGL.so
```

For understanding: where is the instruction from to link against the gl library? I dont find it anywhere

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

seems like i could solve the problem by deleting:

```
sudo apt-get purge libcheese-gtk23, libclutter-1.0-0, libcheese7
```

Though those libraries are needed by e.g. skype or steam.
So i had to reinstall skype and reconfigure steam.

After that now all works great (again)